# fedora 18 installer cannot detect my existing windows 7 partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, fedora

I have 500 gb harddisk.
and the space are allocated to drive ,as follow:
C Drive 100 gb and windows 7 is installed on it,
D Drive 150 gb,
E Drive 150 gb,
F Drive 100 gb.
i would like to install fedora in my f drive.but when i install fedora 18,it does not detect any drive,instead it shows 500 gb as free space.can anybody help me.

Comment: Are you using GPT or MBR partitions?  **Please add this information to your question instead of replying to my comment.**

Answer (score 0):

The symptom of a disk appearing to be unpartitioned when it has partitions is usually caused by one of two problems:

- **Leftover RAID data** -- If the disk had been used in a RAID array, there may be leftover RAID data that can confuse libparted (the library that the Fedora installer uses for partitioning). The result is that the disk appears to be empty. Typing `dmraid -E -r /dev/sda` as `root` usually fixes this problem; but be *100% sure* that you're *not* currently using RAID. Sometimes the computer is configured to use RAID even on a single-disk computer, and removing RAID data that's required could cause serious problems.
- **A damaged partition table** -- Basically, anything that libparted doesn't like causes the disk to appear to be unpartitioned. There are a large number of problems that fall into this category, and you've presented insufficient detail to know if any of them might be true for you. In many (but not all) cases, my [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) program (part of the `gdisk` package in Fedora) can repair the damage. In other cases, you'll need to dig in with `fdisk` or some other tool.

I've written [a Web page about this problem,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/index.html) so consult it for more details. If you need more help, please edit your question to post the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda` (assuming `/dev/sda` is the disk in question). Please post that either as a link or properly formatted (by adding four spaces to the start of each line).